# Jquery/Javascript Refreshing Click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, click

I'm creating a simple game where a player creates a 4 color code by clicking on 6 different colored squares, later on the computer player is suppose to be able to guess what the player has selected but that's to happen much later on. Anyway, the problem I'm running into is with click(). I want it so that when you click on each of the squares the result of which square you click on as well as the order is stored in an array, which is to eventually be the player's 4 color code. So far it looks like the information is being stored but not in the way you would expect. If I click on the orange square for instance, that information is stored 4 times so if I print out the array contents it will look like orange, orange, orange, orange. I want it to reset each time a click happens, if that makes any sense. If I click on blue, purple, orange, green and then print out the array it should say blue, purple, orange, green. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
var colorSelection;
var playerCode = [];
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div.codeOption').mouseenter(function() {

        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
    });

    $('div.codeOption').mouseleave(function() {

        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
    });

});

$('div.codeOption').click(function() {

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        colorSelection = $(this).attr('id');
        playerCode[i] = colorSelection;
        alert(playerCode);
    }

});
```

Comment: mind creating a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sjjLogcL/2/)

you are looping 4 times and setting the same selection each of those 4 times for every click...  You were probably thinking you had to loop through each one and figure out which one was clicked, but your jquery click and subsequent $(this) selector takes care of which one was clicked for you, so no need to loop...  try this instead

```
var colorSelection;
var playerCode = [];
var clickCount = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div.codeOption').mouseenter(function(){

    $(this).fadeTo("fast",0.5);    
        });

  $('div.codeOption').mouseleave(function(){

      $(this).fadeTo("fast",1);
  });



    $('div.codeOption').click(function(){

            colorSelection = $(this).attr('id');
            playerCode [clickCount] =  colorSelection;  
            alert(playerCode);
            clickCount++;

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Seth, Aameer and ajmajmajma. erikrunia is right on the mark though with what I was trying to do. Thinking I had to loop through each "click" was nearly my line of reasoning as well, glad to know that isn't the case. I just finished the jquery lesson at CodeAcademy so I'm still quite new at this, and coding in general for that matter, so this was a big help. Thanks to all who helped me!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.codeOption').click(function(){
...
colorSelection = $(this).attr('id');
playerCode [i] =  colorSelection;  
...
});
```

you are using $(this) in side div.codeOption which will always point to that particular div which has been clicked. Try using something like .each which will do it for all of the divs. Haven't tested it but hope that helps.

```
$('div.codeOption').click(function(){
     $('div.codeOption').each(function(){
         //some code
     });
});
```